# Cannot launch jenkins windows slave after upgrade

Tags: windows, jenkins

I have just updated jenkins to 1.5. My windows slaves were disconnected during the upgrade and now I cannot connect them again. I start the windows slaves with:

```
javaws.exe slave-agent.jnlp
```

I get this error:

[image]

I can remote to the windows slaves just fine so they are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new, known issue due to this [Security Advisory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2013-01-04).  Additional information, including several fixes/workaround can be found [HERE](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/JNLP-slave-no-longer-works-td4650702.html).

Personally, since our Jenkins is on a secured, private network, going to Manage Jenkins ->  Configure Global Security, and under  Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy enable “connect” in the “slave” section, for user “Anonymous” was sufficient to get us working.

Answer (score 1):

In order to always assure correct update, the following steps must occur:

## How to update Jenkins Slave in Windows

1. go to services.msc type "je" to find jenkins slave service and stop it from running
2. do: sc delete jenkinsslave-c__h (or the name the service has)

   1. to know the name of the service, go to services.msc and open "Jenkins Slave" properties (it is auto/ highlighted)
   2. if it is only "marked for deletion" close "Services" window (this will effectively delete the service)
3. go to c:h\ dir (or the dir where jenkins is running) and delete all files, letting workspace dir untouched

   1. for %i in (*) do if not %i == workspace del "%i"
4. open "Java Control Panel" (search "Configure Java" on start button) and set Security to Medium
5. Configure Path where Jenkins worspace will operate at http://server:8080/jenkins/computer/node_to_use/configure
6. go to http://server:8080/jenkins/computer/node_to_use and run "Launch"
7. do: file>install as service; ok.
8. go to services.msc and refresh with F5 in order to appear "Jenkins Slave"
9. stop the service
10. open properties, and in the LogOn tab at "This account:" insert ".\user" being the user the admin user of the machine (or as the tested used via GUI login). Insert the password.
11. Set to automatic start on boot with following conditions:

    1. delayed mode;
    2. 2 retries on failure (1 minute interval)
12. Assure user has needed files and access permissions
13. Go to Computer Management (right click@My Computer > Manage)

    1. System Tools > Event Viewer > (Windows Logs >) Application > right click and choose Properties > "Overwrite events as needed"
14. run Jenkins slave